# Choosing the right current sensor for the PMSM motor drive application

Tags: power-electronics, datasheet, motordriver, pmsm, current-sensor

I have a 400W PMSM motor. It has a rated current of 2.4A with 3000RPM and 108V. The motor datasheet says that it can go upto 4500 RPM with load current of 4A. The motor is HG-KR43. Now I want to read the current feedback of this motor on any two phases.

I need help in choosing the correct LPSR current sensor. The datasheet is somewhat confusing and the LPSR series has many types i.e. 6A, 15A, 25A and 50A. Now there are also specific configurations within the datasheet that help reduce these values as well. Can someone help me understand what configuration and what LPSR current sensor should I use for my application of motor drive.

Thankyou. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd want more than the steady state current to be able to measure transients. Could the motor at all go in reverse? 6A with the standard 2.75 reference voltage and 5V supply voltage couldn't hurt - you could measure up to +/- 6A in transients. Greater than 6A might thin the resolution of your sensor reading more than necessary.